# Can .NET convert "Yes" & "No" to boolean without If?

Tags: .net, casting, boolean

You would think there would be a way using DirectCast, TryCast, CType etc but all of them seem to choke on it e.g.:

```
CType("Yes", Boolean)
```

You get:

> System.InvalidCastException -
>   Conversion from string "Yes" to type
>   'Boolean' is not valid.

Comment: A Boolean is TRUE or FALSE.  Not YES or NO.

Comment: @Ardman, incorrect. Boolean is True, False and FileNotFound

Comment: YES/NO works in Objective-c, and that is the defacto language of the world, just like VB use to be.

Comment: Objective-c, defacto language of the world. What a laugh.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you think about it, "yes" cannot be converted to bool because it is a language and context specific string.

"Yes" is not synonymous with true (especially when your wife says it...!). For things like that you need to convert it yourself; "yes" means "true", "mmmm yeeessss" means "half true, half false, maybe", etc.

Comment: You mean we are missing an Important datatype WifeBoolean :)

Comment: I just let my wife see this answer - she laughed and said it was "Yes".

Comment: Re wife variant.. you also need a time factor and a "last thing I said to her" variable in there too.....

Comment: @Trevor_G, I think all you really need is `bool yes = (conversation.Wife.LastMessage == "Yes" && conversation.ArgumentPotential == 0);`

Comment: Careful though, that code might throw an ArgumentException.

Answer (score 31):

Using this way, you can define conversions from any string you like, to the boolean value you need. 1 is true, 0 is false, obviously.
Benefits: Easily modified. You can add new aliases or remove them very easily.
Cons: Will probably take longer than a simple if. (But if you have multiple alises, it will get hairy)

> ```
> enum BooleanAliases {
>       Yes = 1,
>       Aye = 1,
>       Cool = 1,
>       Naw = 0,
>       No = 0
>  }
>  static bool FromString(string str) {
>       return Convert.ToBoolean(Enum.Parse(typeof(BooleanAliases), str));
>  }
>  // FromString("Yes") = true
>  // FromString("No") = false
>  // FromString("Cool") = true
> ```

Comment: If you want it culturally portable, you can also just have a dictionary with some values, so that you can set it in runtime.

Comment: LOL, I like this over-engineered idea.

Answer (score 20):

No, but you could do something like:

`bool yes = "Yes".Equals(yourString);`

Comment: Genius, simply genius!

Comment: Awesome answer, I wouldn't have thought about that.

Answer (score 5):

C# 6+ version:

```
public static bool StringToBool(string value) => 
    value.Equals("yes",           StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
    value.Equals(bool.TrueString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || 
    value.Equals("1");`
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private static bool GetBool(string condition)
{
    return condition.ToLower() == "yes";
}

GetBool("Yes"); // true
GetBool("No"); // false
```

Or another approach using extension methods

```
public static bool ToBoolean(this string str)
{
    return str.ToLower() == "yes";
}

bool answer = "Yes".ToBoolean(); // true
bool answer = "AnythingOtherThanYes".ToBoolean(); // false
```

Comment: Be careful of the casing of your input.  Maybe use `return (condition.ToUpper() == "YES" ) ? true : false;` instead

Comment: Add more boolean Zen to your code: return condition.ToLower() == "yes"

Answer (score 2):

Slightly off topic, but I needed once for one of my classes to display 'Yes/No' instead of 'True/False' in a property grid, so I've implemented `YesNoBooleanConverter` derived from [`BooleanConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.booleanconverter.aspx) and decorating my property with `<TypeConverter(GetType(YesNoBooleanConverter))> _`...

Answer (score 2):

You Can't. But you should use it as

```
bool result = yourstring.ToLower() == "yes";
```

Answer (score 2):

I like `switch` for this since it's simple and easily scales as needed.  The default pattern catches empty strings and nulls without any fuss.  I also like extension methods, so I end up with this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ToBool(this string str)
    {
        return str?.ToLower() switch
        {
            "true" => true,
            "yes" => true,
            "y" => true,
            "t" => true,
            "1" => true,
            _ => false
        };
    }   
}
```

Usage

```
"Yes".ToBool();  // true
"no".ToBool();   // false
"".ToBool();     // false

string s = null;
s.ToBool();      // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private bool StrToBool(string value)
    {   // could be yes/no, Yes/No, true/false, True/False, 1/0
        bool b = false;
        if (value.Equals("yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || value.Equals(Boolean.TrueString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || value.Equals("1"))
        {
            b = true;
        }
        else if (value.Equals("no", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || value.Equals(Boolean.FalseString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || value.Equals("0"))
        {
            b = false;
        }
        else
        {   // we should't be here 
            b = false;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer that @thelost posted, but I'm reading values from an ADO.Net DataTable and the casing of the string in the DataTable can vary.

The value I need to get as a boolean is in a DataTable named `childAccounts` in a column named `Trades`.

I implemented a solution like this:

```
bool tradeFlag = childAccounts["Trade"].ToString().Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsBoolean(string strValue)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue) && ("1/YES/TRUE".IndexOf(strValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to get this done.

```
rv.Complete = If(reader("Complete") = "Yes", True, False)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Public Function TrueFalseToYesNo(thisValue As Boolean) As String
    Try
        If thisValue Then
            Return "Yes"
        Else
            Return "No"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return thisValue.ToString
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: The question is asking how to convert `"Yes"` / `"No"` to `true` / `false`, not the other way round.

Comment: As yes.  Thanks for the clarification.  Apologies for misreading the OP.  I just happened to have that code fresh in my mind so thought to share it.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering how this piece of code could throw an exception, and if it does, then why it is a good idea to return thisValue.ToString? No offence, but this looks like quite a bad practice.