# Converting string Yes or No to Boolean in vb

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, boolean, data-conversion

i want to convert the string of txtQualified to boolean which in the database was set as bit, but it's not working, error "string was not recognized has a valid Boolean", what should i do please?

```
 Sub verify()
       
        If aggregate >= CutOffPoint.txtMaleCut.Text AndAlso cmbGender.SelectedItem = "Male" Then
            MsgBox("Sorry, You do not Qualify to Offer the Program")
            txtQualified.Text = "No"
            Convert.ToBoolean(txtQualified.Text)
        ElseIf aggregate >= CutOffPoint.txtFemaleCut.Text AndAlso cmbGender.SelectedItem = "Female" Then
            MsgBox("Sorry, You do not Qualify to Offer the Program")
            txtQualified.Text = "No"
            Convert.ToBoolean(txtQualified.Text)
        ElseIf aggregate < less Then
            MsgBox("Sorry, Invalid Entry, Please Entry all Provided Grades")
        Else
            MsgBox("Congratulation, You have Qualified")
            txtQualified.Text = "Yes"
            Convert.ToBoolean(txtQualified.Text)

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can .NET convert "Yes" & "No" to boolean without If?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872710/can-net-convert-yes-no-to-boolean-without-if)

Comment: Why use a TextBox instead of a CheckBox in the first place?

Comment: Also, note that `Convert.ToBoolean` is a function, so if you did use it you would have to assign it to a variable, for example `isQualified = Convert.ToBoolean(someExpression)`.

Comment: Are you sure that `aggregate >= CutOffPoint.txtMaleCut.Text` is the correct check? A .Text property sounds like it should give a string result, so this might be a check by alphabetic ordering instead of by numerical value

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this function to your project:

```
Public function ConvertTextToBoolean(InputStr as String) As Boolean

if InputStr = "No" Then
   Return False
end if

if InputStr = "Yes" Then
   Return True
end if

if not InputStr = "Yes" and not InputStr = "No" Then
   MsgBox("Invalid String")
end if

end function
```

But i don't understand correctly : Do you want to do this without "**if**" !?

Answer (score 0):

Just write a little function to get the Boolean value. You can add some validation if it is possible for the value to be other than Yes and No.

Including the `.Add` method for parameters with the proper database datatype will make the operation safer.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sql = "Insert Into YourTable (ABitField) Values (@BitField);"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BitField", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = GetBoolean(txtQualified.Text)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function GetBoolean(s As String) As Boolean
    Return s = "Yes"
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: `Return s = "Yes"` is shorter as complete body of that GetBoolean