# Using a switch statement within property set function with different types

Tags: c#

I have the following field / property setup:

```
        private bool inpVariable;

        private bool InpVariable
        {
            get { return InpVariable; }
            set
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "Yes":
                        InpVariable = true;
                        break;
                    case "No";
                        InpVariable = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        InpVariable = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type string to type bool.

I am trying to set the InpVariable using a constructor as follows:

```
        public inpClass(string inpVariable)
        {

            InpVariable = inpVariable;

        }
```

Comment: There's no way that `switch (value)` can match `string`s like `"Yes"` and `"No"` when the `value` implicit parameter has the same type as the property, which is `bool`.

Comment: The type of `value` matches the type of the property, here: `bool`. A bool cannot be "Yes" or "No"

Comment: Your constructor has to convert `"Yes"` or `"No"` to `true` or `false` before it can assign `InpVariable`, same as anywhere that you would need to assign a bool bsed on a string value. Or have the constructor accept `bool inpVariable` and push the conversion to the consumer. Why should your class be responsible for that, anyway?

Comment: Also: `return InpVariable;` produces an infinite recursion; you probably meant `return inpVariable;`

Comment: For that matter, the case blocks are *assigning* the property, which is also infinite recursion.

Comment: Don't write non-trivial properties that could silently mangle values, if you can avoid it. Such conversion is better left to the constructor, for example, `InpVariable = inpVariable switch { "Yes" => true, "No" => false, _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Unsupported value {inpVariable}.", nameof(inpVariable)) };`

Comment: But why should the constructor do that, either? Let the consumer mangle it and take responsibility for doing so.

Comment: @madreflection: where to put this logic depends on where it should be put. There's nothing wrong in principle with making this class responsible for parsing, as opposed to having each consumer do it themselves. Whether that's a good idea depends on the context. One place where it almost certainly should not be put is a property setter.

Comment: You said not to silently mangle the value, but doing it in the constructor is no different than doing it in the property. It's still taking responsibility for the conversion. The consumer can do as paulsm4's answer suggests, and it's no longer silent. The consumer makes the choice, and doing so can be trivial. The component needs a boolean value so it should accept a boolean value and not deal with textual representation.

Comment: @madreflection: It is different in that my proposed implementation will not *silently* mangle the value, as it throws on unknown values. (I meant "mangle" as something different from "parse" here.) The component may well need a boolean value; it might also be a clumsy attempt at a parser -- it's not completely clear from the context. If it is not intended to parse data, then yes, it should just a boolean and leave the rest to callers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Points conceded. I glanced over the `throw`. I still think the component should take `bool` instead but now it's a matter of preference rather than principle. I don't think it should take responsibility for conversions unless its *purpose* is to do those conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've declared `InpVariable` as a "bool".

You have many different alternatives.  For example, you can declare a static method to convert text to boolean:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872750/421195
>
> ```
> public static bool ToBoolean(this string str)
> {
>     return str.ToLower() == "yes";
> }
>
> bool answer = "Yes".ToBoolean(); // true
> bool answer = "AnythingOtherThanYes".ToBoolean(); // false
> ```

Or you can define a class.  Or an enum.  Or write an extension method.

It really depends on how you want your application to *USE* "InpVariable".